# How to install EasyClangComplete to autocomplete C++ code in Sublime text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I already downloaded EASYCLANGCOMPLETE package from package control.But it is not working and i donot know what to do know?
I also searched this on stack overflow but did not able to find my answer.Can anyone help me what to do after downloading EASYCLANGCOMPLETE package?

Comment: Give more info. about what you have tried. Did you follow the [getting started instructions](https://niosus.github.io/EasyClangComplete/)?

Comment: First i go to tools,and from command palette,i install the easyClangComplete plugin.But i don't know what to do know?                                                                                                                 I am not getting what to download from clang website(step 2).

Comment: Do you have Clang or LLVM installed already and set up properly? Step 2 does that if you haven't already. I'm guessing you're on Windows, so scroll down in the LLVM 10.0.0 section to the pre-built binaries, select either Windows 32-bit or 64-bit depending on your system, and install it. Alternatively, if you have Cygwin installed, you can install LLVM through it.